# How to call function inside class

Tags: php, function

i have a problem with calling function inside my class

So, this is my code

```
<?php 
    class JESUS {

        public $Name = [];

        public function Update($name,$ver,$desc){
            $var = "Name: ".$name." Version: ".$ver." Description: ".$desc."";
            array_push($this->Name, $var);
        }

    Update('test1','test2','test3');

    }

?>
```

And Update function is not working. Can you tell me how can i make it work?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how classes work.

You'd do

```
$foo = new JESUS;
$foo->Update('test1','test2','test3');
```

*outside* the class.

Comment: But, i was asking, how can i use it inside

Comment: @MichalSmolarek That's answered in my answer. "That's not how classes work." Now, a class function can call another class function by doing `$this->Update()`, but the way you're attempting to do things just isn't how classes are used.

Comment: Ok, so it's not possible. Thanks for answer ;)

Comment: @MichalSmolarek Right. If you want to initialize values when the class is first called, just put it in the constructor.